# Table fields height

Tags: tables

I want to make a table like this table [image]

I tried this :

```
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3.7cm}||p{3.7cm}|p{3.7cm}|p{2.9cm}|  }
  \hline
 KeyWords& Google Scholar& IEEEXplore & ScienceDirect\\
 \hline
 Afghanistan   & AF    &AFG&   004\\   \hline
 Aland Islands&   AX  & ALA   &248\\  \hline
 Albania &AL & ALB&  008\\  \hline
 Algeria    &DZ & DZA&  012\\  \hline
 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

As you can see the fields don't have the same height as I want.

Comment: What's the logic behind the row heights and vertical alignment in the first image you show?

Comment: I believe it will be more comfortable for the eyes

Comment: it's actually harder to scan across a table with so much white space but put `\renewcommand\arraystretch{3}` before your table

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)

Comment: Thank you David Carlisle it works.